# Entity Framework SP (1 column) doesn't show real values

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using an imported Stored Procedure (which returns 1 column, string values) in Entity Framework.
I'm trying to bind a datagridview but i just get the row length and not the real values.
But if i try to iterate the StoredProcedure as a list then i get the real Values.
How can i fix that?

```
For Each item As String In ContextoCatalogoFarmaco.Contexto.spuFARfarmacosTipoSelect
            MessageBox.Show(item)
        Next

DataGridView1.DataSource = ContextCatalogoFarmaco.Context.spuFARfarmacosTipeSelect.tolist()
```

Screenshot of Datagridview and real values http://tinypic.com/r/jrxw11/5

Answer (score 0):

You can't affect the result of a stored procedure directly on a data source. You need to iterate over your result set and store it in a temporary object. Unless you use an ORM like entity framework.